# Convergence of $f \circ g_n$ towards $f \circ g$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $f\in C^1([0,1]\times\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, and $g_n \in C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ that converges uniformly towards $g \in C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ : i.e
$$||g_n-g ||_{\infty}\rightarrow0. \,\, (n\rightarrow +\infty).$$
Can we deduce that :for all $t\in [0,1]$ : $|f(g_n(t),t)-f(g(t),t)|\rightarrow0. \,\, (n\rightarrow +\infty)$ ?

My idea:

Since $f\in C^1$, then $f$ is locally lipschitz : there is $c>0$ such that :
$$|f(g_n(t),t)-f(g(t),t)|\leq c ||g_n-g||_{\infty}.$$

Comment: Do you mean $f \circ g$ (that's `$f \circ g$`) by "$fog$"?

Comment: It is enough that $f(\cdot, t)$ is continuous for each $t$. And for $g_n\to g$, pointwise convergence is also enough

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes